# How I get one variable argument from one method to another

Tags: c#, variables, methods

Hy,

I have the following constuctor:

```
 public partial class SelectSize : Form
    {
        public SelectSize(String name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public String Name
        { get; set; }
```

and I want to get Name to use it in my following method:

```
p private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (((int.Parse(noRows.Text) % 2) == 0) && (((int.Parse(noCols.Text) % 2) == 0)) && ((int.Parse(noRows.Text) ==
            int.Parse(noCols.Text))) && ((int.Parse(noRows.Text) > 6) && ((int.Parse(noRows.Text) > 6))))
        {
            //String name = this.Name;
            PlayMe f = new PlayMe(int.Parse(noCols.Text), int.Parse(noCols.Text), Name);
            this.Hide();
            f.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
```

but i get null reference for Name.

How I transfer one variable to another method?

Sincerly,

Comment: Are both of these methods in same class?

Comment: Yes, they are. Name in constructor comes from another form. The constructor receives its argument corectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now the reason why my above code don't worked.

Thank you all for your help, your good adviced made me to improve my code and to find a solution.

The initial form will look like bellow:

```
 private void nXNGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SelectSize ss = new SelectSize(this);
            ss.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Now SelectSize Form and button_Click is:

```
public partial class SelectSize : Form
    {
        MainWin f1;
        public SelectSize(MainWin f1)
        {
            this.f1 = f1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public String Name
        { get; set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (((int.Parse(noRows.Text) % 2) == 0) && (((int.Parse(noCols.Text) % 2) == 0)) && ((int.Parse(noRows.Text) ==
                int.Parse(noCols.Text))) && ((int.Parse(noRows.Text) > 6) && ((int.Parse(noRows.Text) > 6))))
            {
                //String name = this.Name;
                PlayMe f = new PlayMe(int.Parse(noCols.Text), int.Parse(noCols.Text), f1.Name);
                this.Hide();
                f.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this.Name is null then a different Constructor has been called or null was actually passed to the constructor. Check on that. 
It may, of course, have been overwritten in the meantime. E.g. from our point of view. as we don't know all of your code, this.Name = null; could be in `InstanciateComponent()`.

Well, it could happen that both methods are not executed on the same (identical) instance of this class. Compare the ojbjects' addresses if they really are equal.

Btw, you should call `this.Name` rather `this.name` and `InstanciateComponent()` should be `instanciateComponent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Name will be null unless you set it. You need to give a default value to get it.

Comment: Name is not null when it's received in the constructor, but in button1_Click() is null :-(

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will be null reference because you don't initialize it, how will you set the value for **name** ?

Comment: The name has a value in SelectSize(String name) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

_button1_Click_?
I guess you have a collision with Form1.Name

When you write

```
this.Name = "value";
```

you try to change the name of your Form1

UPD:

Try this:

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class SelectSize : Form
    {
        public SelectSize(String name)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public String Name
        { get; set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this.Name); // It must show a string from SelectSize's constructor
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I change the name of Form1 and i use this name as an argument in PlayMe form signature PlayMe f = new PlayMe(int.Parse(noCols.Text), int.Parse(noCols.Text), Name);